# Why when I using track by $index will always remove the last element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I am using ng-repeat with track by $index option, I can not delete correct element from array or object (ng-repeat will always remove the last element).

this is add button (add button created a new table) :

```
 $scope.current = 0;
    $scope.addHocKPIs = function () {
        $scope.repeatTable.push('test' + $scope.current);
        $scope.current += 1;
    };
```

this is table code:

```
<table id="addHocKPIsTable{{$index}}" ng-repeat="table in repeatTable track by $index">
    <td>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr style="display: table-row">
                    <th style="height: 46px;">
                        <button type="button" role="button" ng-click="removeAddHocKPIs($index, table)">
                            <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
                        </button>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</table>
```

and this is remove button js code :

```
$scope.removeAddHocKPIs = function (index, table) {
    $scope.repeatTable.splice(index, 1);
};
```

when I delete second table from array, deleting last table (so "test3")

it will deleted "test1" value and new array: [image]  but deleted table test3 (like a photo [image])

Answer (score 1):

Angular is not deleting the last element, it's deleting the element you wanted and updating the `$index` bindings. Say the array contains three elements; when you remove the second, the third element becomes the second and its index value becomes 1 instead of 2, since you now have two elements in the array.

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfuhdx6p/). Notice that when you click on the remove input, the correct person is removed and the indexes are updated.

Comment: Funny how i just ran into this and figure out the problem was being caused by the trackby index. After cooling my head i wanted to know why it was not working and search for a response, and here is your response explaining exactly what i was experiencing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I used  `ng-repeat="table in repeatTable track by $id(table)`" and it works. 
My source : [ng-repeat with track by](http://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7119)